# How to make `needrestart` not defer restarting some services

Tags: systemd, apt, unattended-upgrades

With `unattended-upgrades` duly set up to automatically do upgrades, reboots and all, I'm stumped to find output like this in its daily report sometimes:

> ```
> ...
> Restarting services...
>  /etc/needrestart/restart.d/systemd-manager
>  systemctl restart accounts-daemon.service networkd-dispatcher.service polkit.service systemd-networkd.service systemd-resolved.service systemd-timesyncd.service systemd-udevd.service
>
> Service restarts being deferred
>  systemctl restart apt-daily-upgrade.service
>  systemctl restart systemd-journald.service
>  systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
>  systemctl restart unattended-upgrades.service
> ...
> ```

I understand this is output from `needrestart`. I do not understand what sets the services that *do* get restarted apart from the ones that don't. What configuration do I need to change to make it restart *all* these services unattendedly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `needrestart` package maintains an exclusion list of services that should not be restarted automatically in `/etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf`. Look for the `$nrconf{override_rc}` setting.

Be careful modifying this list. Based on my quick glance, it seems like most of these default exclusions are due to user reported issues that arise when restarting services. A lot of the exclusions in that file have a comment with a Debian bug tracker number that explains why the exclusion is there.

Looking at the example in your question, these exclusions are causing your services to not be restarted automatically:

- `apt-daily-upgrade.service` and `unattended-upgrades.service` aren't restarted because restarting those can kill the running `needrestart` process if it was started by those services. This is documented in bug [#862840](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=862840).
- `systemd-journald.service` isn't being restarted because it breaks a lot of other services. This is documented in bug [#771122](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=771122). However, this question is 2 years old and this exclusion isn't present in newer versions (3.4+) of `needrestart`. It's not excluded on my Ubuntu 22.04 system.
- `systemd-logind.service` isn't restarted because doing so kills your running X server session. This is documented in bug [#798097](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=798097).